# Saber se Activity está aberta (BroadcastReceiver ou service)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Gostaria de implementar uma função que pudesse verificar se Activity está aberta, pois quando eu receber a notificação através do GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) se a activity tiver aberta vai apenas carregas as informações na mesma, se tiver fechada notificar o usuário e através dessa notificação ele abrir a Activity com as informações. Quero fazer isso dentro de um service, vlw!

Comment: Não resolveu, pelo menos no service não deu certo. Erro > FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getTasks() from pid=3792, uid=10096 requires android.permission.GET_TASKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma variável estática dentro da `Activity`, assim você pode defini-la explorando o [ciclo de vida](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html?hl=pt-br) `onStart()` e `onStop()`. Veja:

```
class MinhaActivity extends Activity {
     static boolean active = false;

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         active = true;
      } 

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         active = false;
      }
}
```

Para acessar e verificar se a variável está ativa ou inativa, você pode fazer desta forma:

```
if(MinhaActivity.active){
    //esta ativa
} else {
    //não está ativa
}
```

Comment: mas como eu irei acessar essa variável através do service para obter o valor verdadeiro ou falso?

Comment: @RubensVentura editei.

Comment: deu certo aqui, mas quando minimizo o app, é como estivesse finalizado, no caso eu devo usar o active = false; no OnDestroy ?

Comment: @RubensVentura tanto para o onStop quanto para o onDestroy você pode usar o active = false. Vai funcionar assim.

Comment: Obrigado manow!